# How to retrieve data from Firebase Realtime to the flutter app in a lisview

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking to retrieve data stored in Firebase Realtime database and display it in a new page in a lisview, how can I achieve that. So far I can retrieve and print it out in a console terminal.

My code is below:

class BarcodesResultPreviewWidget extends StatelessWidget {
FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('ScannedResults');

```
    body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    previewView,
    //printing scanned results
    Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, position) {
          return BarcodeItemWidget(preview.barcodeItems[position]);


        },
        itemCount: preview.barcodeItems.length,

      ),

    ),
    FlatButton(
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Text('Save',),
      onPressed: () {

        databaseRef.push().set({
          'ScannedItem': preview.barcodeItems
              .map((barCodeItem) => barCodeItem.toJson())
              .toString(),
        });

      },
    ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch the data into a new page and build listview, try something like this:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: FutureBuilder(
    future: databaseRef.once(),
    // future: FirebaseDatabase.instance
    //     .reference()
    //     .child("ScannedResults")
    //     .once(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
        return new Text('Loading....');
      if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
      List scannedItemsValues = [];
      snapshot.data.value.forEach(
          (_, values) => scannedItemsValues.add(values["ScannedItem"]));
      print(scannedItemsValues);
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: scannedItemsValues.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          // build your listView here
          print(scannedItemsValues[index]);
          return Text(scannedItemsValues[index]);
        },
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for your response, yes I am looking to fetch the data from Firebase Realtime Database in a new page

Comment: Below is the method I use to get or retrieve data to the console:

Comment: void getData(){
    databaseRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key,values) {
        print(values["ScannedItem"]);
      });
    });

  }

Comment: Okay, a moment, let me update my answer to use this function.

Comment: I have updated my answer. The code should be in the last part.

Comment: Thank you but I am getting this error:                                                                                          The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("ScannedItem")

Comment: The error is at this line :                                                                                                                      return Text(scannedItems[index]["ScannedItem"]);

Comment: Check now. I have updated it to work just like your getData() function.

Comment: Hi Peter, sorry for the late response. I did test it out and it managed to work, thank you again so much for your help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Just one question, do you know any free open source Flutter library that caters for scanning vehicle license disk, because currently I am using the barcode_scanner package and it uses Scanbok SDK which you have to purchase the license after 30 days trial. I have been looking for a free one for Flutter and I have not found it. Your help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So glad I could help, you can mark the answer as accepted so other users can easily find it. No, I have no idea. I have not done anything on scanning vehicle license.